# issue displaying variations in custom template using WPeC 3.8.9.2

Tags: theme-development, wp-query, loop, plugin-wp-e-commerce

I’m having trouble displaying variations in a custom built template,
each time i call the wpsc function have_variation_groups() within my loop i get the following php error

commerce/wpsc-includes/product-template.php on line 1419
[22-Nov-2012 23:27:39] PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function have_variation_groups() on a non-object in /home/tofapost/public_html/sandbox/wp/wp-content/plugins/wp-e-commerce/wpsc-includes/product-template.php on line 1419.

have_variation_groups() is being called inside a WP_Query loop like so;

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'wpsc-product', 'posts_per_page' => -1);
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();

   ... 

<?php if (wpsc_have_variation_groups()) { ?>
<fieldset>
    <legend>
        <?php _e( 'Product Options', 'wpsc'); ?>
    </legend>
    <div class="wpsc_variation_forms">
        <table>
            <?php while (wpsc_have_variation_groups()) : wpsc_the_variation_group();
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td class="col1">
                    <label for="<?php echo wpsc_vargrp_form_id(); ?>">
                        <?php echo wpsc_the_vargrp_name(); ?>:</label>
                </td>
                <?php /** the variation HTML and loop */?>
                <td class="col2">
                    <select class="wpsc_select_variation" name="variation[<?php echo wpsc_vargrp_id(); ?>]"
                    id="<?php echo wpsc_vargrp_form_id(); ?>" <?php while (wpsc_have_variations())
                    : wpsc_the_variation(); ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo wpsc_the_variation_id(); ?>" <?php echo wpsc_the_variation_out_of_stock();
                        ?>>
                            <?php echo wpsc_the_variation_name(); ?>
                        </option>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </table>
    </div>
    <!--close wpsc_variation_forms-->
</fieldset>
<?php } ?> 

    ...

endwhile;
```

Whats strange is other wpsc functions like, wpsc_the_product_id() and wpsc_product_has_stock() work while no functions related to variations do...

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the default wpsc-products_page.php template, it uses

```
while (wpsc_have_products()) :  wpsc_the_product();
```

instead of have_posts() and the_posts() to setup the loop.

The wpsc_the_product() function sets up a global $wpsc_variations object that the product variation functions use.

I think in order to use wpsc_the_product() you need your query to be the global $wp_query, but you can setup $wpsc_variations yourself after you open your loop:

```
while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
    global $wpsc_variations;
    $wpsc_variations = new wpsc_variations( get_the_ID() );
```

That hopefully should get all the product variation functions working.

This is the full wpsc_the_product() function.  It also sets up global $wpsc_custom_meta, which could potentially have a similar affect on custom meta related functions, so that is something else you might need to consider.

```
/**
 * wpsc the product function, gets the next product,
 * @return nothing
 */
function wpsc_the_product() {
    global $wpsc_custom_meta, $wpsc_variations;
    the_post();
    $wpsc_custom_meta = new wpsc_custom_meta( get_the_ID() );
    $wpsc_variations = new wpsc_variations( get_the_ID() );
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: brillant, thanks djrmom! i spent a day(+) trying to figure this out. It seems so obvious after reading your answer. Creating a new instance of wpsc_variations() did the trick. i'm using the indispensable 'ACF' plugin for all custom meta, so i don't believe wpsc_custom_meta will be needed.